# Email client with setting sync

Tags: email, email-client

I am looking for an email client. It can be destkop or web app too.

I manage five emails on three computers, so it would be good if it would have a feature like "setting sync".

Comment: A gmail account can be configured to act as a POP client for up to 5 addresses....

Comment: That was my first thought (+1). If you ***do*** want to use a desktop app, then use IMAP, not POP to send/fetch mail

Answer (score 3):

Syncing in both directions is one of the key features of the IMAP protocol for arbitrary folders. For example in [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) you can additionally define the synchronization options per account and folder, if they should be always downloaded etc. This allows to have the emails in sync everywhere and optionally still on the devices themselves.

Comment: I using Thunderbird right now, but I want to sync the settings, too

Comment: What settings are you speaking of?

Comment: For example if I want to view my emails on a different destkop, I only have to login once or just copy the setting files from my pendrive

Comment: Copying the settings (with stored passwords for mailboxes) is possible for TB.